# Cannot sign in to azure services within an azure function

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-functions

I need to scale an azure sql database two times a day.

**I created an azure function**

[image: azure function]

**and set the identity access**

[image: identity access]

**this is the function body**

[image: function body]

Now, when I run the function I've got this 2 errors

**Error 1**

[image: Error 1]

**Error 2**

[image: Error 2]

I understand that the second error ('this.Client.SubscriptionId' cannot be null) is true because I can see just two lines under that the user has no subscription.

But I don't understand why the

```
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId '< GUID-SUBSCRIPTION >'
```

command generates the first error

> Set-AzContext : Please provide a valid tenant or a valid subscription

I have already checked and the tenantID is the one that contains the function.
So for the subscriptionId that is the one that contains the function.

Should I assign a role to the function?
Should I use a different authentication method?

Comment: Any special reason why you want to use Azure function? May I give you steps how to do the same using Azure Automation? That's the way I do the same for a few organizations

Comment: None in particular. I really appreciate an advice to how to do it with automation, please. Thanks a lot

Comment: Azure Function PowerShell is equal to Azure Automation. I did similar work using Azure function for my Cosmos DB but don't have SQL server.

Comment: yes, in fact  I've tried the same procedure with azure functions and I've got this error "The term 'New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerContext' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again." Do you know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below I will show you to how to achieve this by using Azure Automation. I am providing an scenario where the requirement is to have a database at S2(50 DTU's) from 7A.M to 7 P.M and rest of the hours in Basic Edition (5 DTU's). This activity has to be performed daily.

**Step 1: Create your Automation Account:**

To do the Automation you should create an automation account. Add the details for the Automation account and proceed with the creation.

[image]

**Step 2: Create a Runbook under the Automation account you created**

Click on Add a Runbook Icon and create the run book with PowerShell work flow as run book type.

[image]

[image]

**Step-3: Publish the Runbook**

Copy [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Azure-SQL-Database-e957354f) script and publish it in the runbook

[image]

**Step-4: Creation of credential for the runbook**

create a credential with the server admin user and password like the one I mentioned in the below screenshot.

[image]

**Step-5: Scheduling the run book**

You can decide up on the time where you want to upscale and down scale your database. But you need to create separate run book for each of the options.

[image]

[image]

**Step-6: Configure Parameter setting**

Configure the parameter setting for the Runbook like the server name, database name, Edition, Perf Level and the credential

Edition: Basic, Standard, Premium
Perf Level: Basic, S0, S1, S2, P1, P2, P3

In this case I am downscaling my database from S1 to S0

[image]

[image]

[image]

It Successfully downgraded to S0.

For more information, please read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jerryjacob1/scaling-an-azure-sql-database-using-azure-automation) article.

Comment: Hi, the procedure works but I have a question: I've tried the same procedure with azure functions and I've got this error "The term 'New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerContext' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again." Do you know why?